# Mysql insert return not getting back to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Well I am trying to insert data to a MySQL database. The data is getting inserted successfull. But I am not getting back the return msg after the successful insertion back to ajax. Also I am using the lastest jquery version and PHP version.

The script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data_form').on("submit",() => {
      var formData = $('#data_form').serialize();
      if (!$.active) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '../../../controller/add_user.php',
          data :formData,
          cache: false,
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseJSON.message);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

add_user.php

```
<?php
include_once('../model/database_11.php');
$db_obj = new Dbconnection();
$dbconn = $db_obj->ConnectToDB();

class admin
{
    public $dbconn;
    public $name;
    public $account_type;
    public $telephone = null;
    public $mobile;
    public $address;
    public $pincode;
    public $email_user;
    public $gender;
    public $dob;
    public $status;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $query;

    public function __construct($dbconn, $name, $account_type, $telephone, $mobile, $address, $pincode, $email_user, $gender, $dob, $status, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->dbconn = $dbconn;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->account_type = $account_type;
        $this->telephone = $telephone;
        $this->mobile = $mobile;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->pincode = $pincode;
        $this->email_user = $email_user;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob));
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    function adduser()
    {
        $this->query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID_USER`, `WEB_USERNAME`, `WEB_USERPASSWORD`, `USER_TYPE`, `NAME`, `IMAGE`, `TELEPHONE`, `MOBILE`, `ADDRESS`, `PIN`, `EMAIL`, `GENDER`, `DATE_OF_BIRTH`, `STATUS`) VALUES (NULL, '$this->username', '$this->password', '$this->account_type', '$this->name', NULL, '$this->telephone', '$this->mobile', '$this->address', '$this->pincode', '$this->email_user', '$this->gender', '$this->dob', '$this->status');";
        if ($this->dbconn->query($this->query) === TRUE) {
            return "200";
        } else {
            return "500";
        }
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->dbconn->close();
    }

}
extract($_POST);
$admin = new admin($dbconn, $name, $account_type, $telephone, $mobile, $address, $pincode, $email_user, $gender, $dob, $status, $username, $password);
$res = $admin->adduser();
echo $res;
?>
```

I tried changing he echo statement to http_response_code. But still it's not working.

Comment: _"I tried changing he echo statement to http_response_code."_ - that makes little sense; one creates output to be send as the response body, whereas the other only sets the response status code.

Comment: `console.log(data.message);` - why should the response be an object and have a `message` property - when what you output on the server side, contains no such thing? You should be giving back a proper JSON response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you have seen in comments you need to send back a json

```
function adduser()
{
    $response = array();

    $this->query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID_USER`, `WEB_USERNAME`, `WEB_USERPASSWORD`, `USER_TYPE`, `NAME`, `IMAGE`, `TELEPHONE`, `MOBILE`, `ADDRESS`, `PIN`, `EMAIL`, `GENDER`, `DATE_OF_BIRTH`, `STATUS`) VALUES (NULL, '$this->username', '$this->password', '$this->account_type', '$this->name', NULL, '$this->telephone', '$this->mobile', '$this->address', '$this->pincode', '$this->email_user', '$this->gender', '$this->dob', '$this->status');";

    if ($this->dbconn->query($this->query) === TRUE) {
        $response['status'] = "success";
        $response['message'] = "User added successfully";
    } else {
        $response['status'] = "error";
        $response['message'] = "Error adding user: " . $this->dbconn->error;
    }

    return json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: It's not advisable to push database error info back to the client-side explicitly. It should be logged as an exception instead. Otherwise in a live environment it can cause an accidental security breach if it reveals sensitive information about the environment, which an attacker could then use to make a more targeted hacking attempt. The OP would be better to enable error reporting for their database library, and then also enable PHP error logging. Manually checking for SQL errors also clutters the codebase unnecessarily, and thus increases the coding/testing/maintenance overhead.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that , but this guy is learning about the basics and how he will understand on frontend what error it was

Comment: IMHO that's not a reason to encourage bad habits. People tend to take code they find online and use it without questioning, especially if they're not very familiar with PHP, or coding in general. It doesn't take a lot of effort to set up PHP properly to handle errors, and then it's all ready for them for them to use it in a good way, and get into that mindset from the beginning. Bad habits are harder to break than good ones are to teach initially.

Comment: It's actually under development. So i need to make sure that things are working well, then log the db errors as exception. So when it goes live, I will definitely make sure that these things are handled.

Comment: @DennisBenny It's too late by that time, because then you've already written the code and are deploying it. Actually though _your_ code (as shown in the question) is not really making this mistake - although you're unnecessarily checking for SQL errors manually, you aren't outputting them to the client. What you _should_ be doing is just enabling SQL error reporting in your Db library (e.g. PDO or mysqli or whatever you use) and then errors will be raised by PHP automatically without you needing to write code specifically to check it...

Comment: ... @DennisBenny (continued...)  then you can _either_ configure PHP to show errors in the script output (which is fine for a development or test environment) or log them to a file (which is more secure and is essential for your live environment) - and then you don't have to change code in order to deploy to a different environment, you only have to change the PHP config in the environment.